# Can't find any way to get request headers

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping, request-headers

I'm trying to get the `request headers` using vba. In other languages like `python` there is a very easy way to get that `.headers`. However, in case of vba I'm getting stuck.
I know though there is a way in vba to get `response headers` by using `.getAllResponseHeaders`.

How can I get `request headers` using vba?

This is how I got `response headers`:

```
Sub GetRequestHeaders()
    Const URL$ = "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/web-scraping"
    Dim Http As New XMLHTTP60, S$

    With Http
        .Open "GET", URL, False
        .send
        S = .getAllResponseHeaders
        MsgBox S
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: What your python code is printing out above is response headers. Where are you printing request headers? req is the response ... <class 'requests.models.Response'>

Comment: Right you are @QHarr. That is indeed response headers. However, what I wanted to achieve is get the cookies on the fly (instead of hardcoding) but `xmlhttp` request doesn't have that feature so I got success using `serverxmlhttp` request.

Comment: Indeed. That is a slightly different question and I would have referred you here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39801506/6241235  .  Nice answer that one! The answer to your above question is kinda as per below.

Comment: Check out what I've posted out there in your linked post. Perhaps the easiest one @QHarr.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Python `.headers` (assuming using `requests` library) provides the response headers, not the request headers. You add custom request headers in the dict passed with the `get`. Just as you have seen you can read response headers in vba with `getAllResponseHeaders` and send custom headers with `setRequestHeader` in key,value pairs.

I would normally use something like Fiddler/Dev tools network tab/Wireshark to see what request headers are sent then mimic those or read the associated API guidance specifying what custom request headers are expected.

Here is a snapshot of Fiddler request header capture for that url

[image]

There might be a way with WinHTTP using [winhttpqueryheaders](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/desktop/api/winhttp/nf-winhttp-winhttpqueryheaders) but haven't researched enough and it is far simpler to just use the network tab in most cases.

There is no method associated with the xmlhttp request/response to get the request headers. Have a look at the [specification](https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/#the-response-attribute) (WHATWG living [standard](https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/)) for associated methods (may be some variation in VBA implementation):

[image]

To deal with cookies look at MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP. [Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39709562/how-to-set-and-get-jsessionid-cookie-in-vba/39801506#39801506).

Answer (score 0):

You should set your request headers programmatically with a .setRequestHeader() method or it'll be default IE settings. 
Why do you need to get back the data you've already got?

Comment: Is it supposed to be an answer `why do i need this` @Irregular Expression? Btw, where did i ask how to set request headers? My question is how can I get request headers? Thanks.

Comment: There's no API in XMLHTTP to get *request* headers. You can log/monitor your networking to check for **unexpected** headers in your requests, also you can (and should) set all **expected** headers by yourself with setRequestHeaders(). That's all.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37120655/how-do-i-get-the-request-headers-of-a-winhttp-request?rq=1 - maybe, this'll be helpful.